# When we fix a basis of a vector space, do we fix a basis for its dual also?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space. Suppose we fix a basis of $V$, say the standard basis $\{\boldsymbol e_1, ..., \boldsymbol e_n\}$. Does this choice of basis for $V$ "automatically" fix a basis for $V^*$? Or are we free to choose whatever basis we want for $V^*$, regardless of choice of basis for $V$?

Comment: There are sets which form a basis for $V^*$, and sets which do not.

What you "choose" as your preferred basis makes no difference one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a basis $b_1, \dots, b_n$ of $V$ there is a corresponding *dual basis* $b_1^*, \dots, b_n^*$ of $V^*$ given by
$$b_i^*(b_j) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if $i = j$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise,} \end{cases}$$
i.e., by
$$b_i^*\biggl(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j b_j\biggr) = a_i.$$
So, in that sense, by choosing a basis of $V$, you also choose a basis of $V^*$.

However, if you want to consider another basis of $V^*$, you are free to do so; there are many more to choose from.

Answer (score 2):

You're free to choose whatever basis you want.

But as a matter of convenience, the basis $\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n$, where 
$\phi_i$ has the properties that
$$
\phi_i(e_i) = 1\\
\phi_i(e_j) = 0~~~ (j =ne i)
$$
will turn out to be very nice for most computations you want to do, so folks often use it.

Answer (score 1):

For a **finite-dimensional** space, yes. The dual basis to $e_1,\ldots,e_n$
is $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ where $f_i(e_j)=\delta_{ij}$ (Kronecker delta).